# Combining jQuery Serialize Array Script with Submit Button

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using the following form to allow visitors to submit their answers to tests:

```
<form action="grade.php" method="post" id="quiz">
  <ol>
    <li style="display: none;">
      <?php echo join ($Base, ''); ?>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <input type="hidden" name="PreviousURL" value="<?php echo $MyURL; ?>" id="url" />
  <input type="hidden" name="user_token" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['user_token']) ? $_POST['user_token'] : '' ; ?>" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Quiz" />
</form>
```

I would like to use jQuery's serialize array function to prevent the form from submitting if a user hasn't answered all the questions.

But I don't understand how to combine the jQuery script with the form. I assume I replace #myform with my form's ID ('quiz'). But do I just post the jQuery script at the bottom of the page?

I tried that, but it doesn't work; if I just answer one question, then click the submit button, the form forwards me to the results page.

```
<script>
  $('#myform').submit(function(event){
  var answers = $('#myform').serializeArray();
  $.each(answers , function(index,value){
   if(value == ''){
   event.preventDefault();
   alert('you did not answer all the questions');
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are allowed to use HTML5, then you could always use the `required` attribute on your required input fields to prevent submission.

Other than that, `serializeArray()` returns an array of objects which look like

```
{
    name: <input_name>,
    value: <input_value>
}
```

so in your javascript, instead of checking `if(value == '')` try `if(value.value == '')` as you are currently checking the object against a string, not the actual value.

Comment: I changed value to value.value, but it still isn't working. However, I like your suggestion about the required attribute; I wasn't even aware of that. It seems like that would be the best solution, actually. I'll probably choose this as the correct answer as soon as I get that set up and working.

Answer (score 0):

Try edit script to these

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#quiz").submit(function(){
        var answers = $('#quiz').serializeArray();
        for(var i=0;i<answers.length;i++){
            if(answers[i].value == ''){
                alert('you did not answer all the questions');
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Ryan Yu - Thanks, but that isn't working for me, either. I just realized that I'm linked to two or three different jQuery scripts, so maybe I have a conflict there. code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js, code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js I'll have to spend some time working on that.